# Transforming a tensor expression

Tags: matrix, series-expansion, tensors, field-theory

I have the expression

$\qquad\sqrt{\det[\gamma^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}]}$

Basiclly, I need to expand this expression in some form like : $trF^4 + (trF^2)^2 + \sqrt{\det[F_{\mu \nu}]}$,
where $\gamma^{\mu \nu}$ is a Dirac matrix in $SO(8)$ and $F_{\mu \nu}$ is  the FieldStrength tensor.

Maybe I am writing it wrong or maybe I have to load some kind of package into Mathematica.

If somebody could help me I would appreciate.

Comment: Aren’t Dirac matrices in 8 Euclidean dimensions $16\times 16$? It seems like if there is an identity, the right side must have terms with 8, not 4, powers of $F$.

Comment: I am not sure how do you relate that but you just have to keep in mind that  are antisymmetric .

Comment: What I am asking here is how to write in Mathematica, since you were the one who said you should come here since this is the right place, and now you talk about physics, what a contradiction ?

Comment: Mathematica doesn’t know anything about Dirac matrices in any dimension. You would have to construct them or find a package that does this. Hopefully someone else will know of such a package. And as far as I know, it doesn’t have built-in support for symbolic tensors such as $F$, although there definitely are packages that add this.

Comment: Finally, even if you managed to construct a huge 8th degree polynomial in the elements of $F$, it isn’t going to automatically decompose it into invariants involving traces of powers of $F$. Again, you are going to have to write that decomposition code yourself or find a package.

Comment: Although your expression may be of interest to physicists, the identity you seek is a purely mathematical identity that is independent of physical laws. Dirac matrices, antisymmetric tensors, determinants, square roots, traces, etc. have mathematical meaning regardless of whether electrons and other Dirac spinors exist in nature.

Comment: And so my first question to you was not a physics question but a mathematical one.

Comment: Still can not believe how precise you want to be about math and physics, what is the matter if I call the question physical or mathematical, the important things is that none of us knows it and it is relevant how you call it.

Comment: and by the way I did crack it by my self , thanks for the 'help'.

Comment: Congratulations. I will be sure not to irritate you with my preciseness in the future.